# Property does not exist on type and parameter implicitly has an any type

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, firebase

I keep getting this error and I have tried to put "noImplicitAny": false in tsconfig.json and it didn't work and on the 'Property does not exist on type' I haven't tried anything so far.

Any help would be great.

```
//HTML component
//Input for text
<input
class="chatInput"
[(ngModel)]="message"
(keydown)="handleSubmit($event)"
/>

//Button on click send messege
<button class="chatButton" (click)=send()>Send</button>
```

```
//Imports for chat
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-form',
  templateUrl: './chat-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-form.component.css']
})
export class ChatFormComponent implements OnInit {
//Message to string
  message!: string;
  
//Private chat
  constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

//Its giving me an error property does not exist on "sendMesage"
  send(){
    this.chat.sendMessage(this.message);
  }

//When pressed on enter send message
//I get an error: parameter "event" implicitly has an 'any' type
  handSubmit(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
      this.send();
    }
  }

}
```

```
//Chat service Ts is empty, do I need to pass something here or ?
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Please share `ChatService` class. Let me check ChatService.

Answer (score 0):

You can write message like this.

message:any = ''

Answer (score 0):

`ChatService` cannot be empty if you are trying to access a class method in it. It should have the method `sendMessage` in it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ChatService {
  constructor() { }
  
  sendMessage() {
    // Message Logic
  }
}
```